# Displaying array values in laravel 5.2

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, has-many

I have the following `hasMany()` relationship in `App\User.php` ,

```
public function partner_preference_occupation()
{
    return $this-hasMany('App\Models\User\PartnerPreferenceOccupation', 'user_id');

}
```

The following is my PartnerPreferenceOccupation Model,

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\User;

use App\Models\BaseModel,
App\Models\ValidationTrait;

class PartnerPreferenceOccupation extends BaseModel {

use ValidationTrait;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->__validationConstruct();
}

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'partner_preferences_occupation';  

protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'occupation_id');
protected $dates = array();
public $uploadPath = array();

protected function setRules() {

    $this->val_rules = array();
}

protected function setAttributes() {

    $this->val_attributes = array();
}

public function occupation_name() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Master\OccupationModel', 'occupation_id');
    }

}
```

I want to display the array of occupation name in my view. I tried the following code, but it fails.

```
{{$obj->partner_preference_occupation ? $obj-partner_preference_occupation->occupation_name->name : null}}
```

The error is as follows,

```
Undefined property:Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$occupation_name
```

How can I display them.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it,
As it is an array of values to be fetched, I used foreach to display them in my view as,

```
@if($occ=$obj->partner_preference_occupation->lists('occupation_name'))
@foreach($occ as $oc)
{{$oc->name}}
@endforeach
@endif
```

occupatoin_name is the name of my relationship that I used in my model. And that worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in `$obj-partner_preference_occupation->occupation_name->name`

Should be `$obj->partner_preference_occupation->occupation_name->name`

Make sure that `occupation_name` exists in the collection. You can check by doing the following in your View:

```
dump( $obj->partner_preference_occupation );
```

It might help you identify where the issue lies.

Also, to display a collection as an array, you can use the `toArray()` method, e.g.:

```
$obj->partner_preference_occupation->toArray()
```

Comment: Thanks Niraj, When I used, dump($obj->partner_preference_occupation) I got like this

array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 36
    "user_id" => 93
    "occupation_id" => 19
    "created_at" => "2017-02-09 12:12:17"
    "updated_at" => "2017-02-09 12:12:17"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 37
    "user_id" => 93
    "occupation_id" => 9
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
]
 how can I get each occupation id's name respectively

Comment: I see. It means you don't have a relationship between `occupation_id` and the `occupation` table. You should start by creating this relation in your model.

Comment: But I've written the below code in my App\User
public function partner_preference_occupation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User\PartnerPreferenceOccupation', 'user_id');
    }

and defined a relationship in my model as follows,
public function occupation_name() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Master\OccupationModel', 'occupation_id');
    }

Comment: Please have a look at my model which I posted in my question.

Comment: That happens when you do `dump( $obj->partner_preference_occupation->occupation_name ):`?